# PostGIS Spatial Relationships query performance

Tags: postgis, st-intersects

I have a very large dataset contains over 700 million points and a polygon dataset as a buffer zone.

My task is to extract all points inside the buffer zone and create a new table.

Below is my code. I test it with a small point dataset and it works fine.

```
create table schema1.result as

select point.* from

schema1.site as point, schema2.buffer as poly

Where ST_Intersects(point.geo_loc,poly.wkb_geometry);
```

Unfortunately, the query lasted for 1 day and showed no signs to finish.

Is there any advice to optimise my code to speed up the query?

Update: The output of Explain

> "Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..17773703.88 rows=6789472 width=208)"
>
> "  ->  Seq Scan on buffer poly  (cost=0.00..18.50 rows=850 width=32)"
>
> "  ->  Index Scan using idx_site on site point  (cost=0.41..20902.23
> rows=799 width=208)"
>
> "        Index Cond: (geo_loc && poly.wkb_geometry)"
>
> "        Filter: st_intersects(geo_loc, poly.wkb_geometry)"
>
> "JIT:"
>
> "  Functions: 6"
>
> "  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true,
> Deforming true"

Comment: Do you have a GiST index on `point.geo_loc` and/or `poly.wkb_geometry`? Could you show the output of [explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) with the query?

Comment: Hi @MikeT, Thanks for your reply. I believe I have created index on both point.geo_loc and poly.wkb_geometry.   Also, I have added the Explain output to the original post.

Comment: have you `ANALYZE`d the tables after creating the indices? Also, someone else may correct me, but you could add `AND ST_DWITHIN(point.geo_loc,poly.wkb_geometry, 1)` to the where and it may use the spatial indices more efficiently/at all.

Comment: What is the min, max and avg `ST_NPoints` of your polygons? How many are there? Do they all have a regular shape?

Comment: And most importantly, do they overlap? Since, if a point may be found in more than one poly, a `JOIN` will fetch it for each match; you'd need to add a `DISTINCT` which will be significantly slower. In that case, an `EXISTS` may indeed be the better choice. If, however, a point always only intersects with one polygon, a `JOIN` is likely the better plan.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that the comment from @Hugh_Kelley (including ST_DWithin(x, y, 1) improved the performance of query of mine by a factor of 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what's going on here is that when you write:

`from schema1.site as point, schema2.buffer as poly`

PostgreSQL is doing a `CROSS JOIN` between the two tables. When multiple tables are listed in the `FROM` clause postgres uses a `CROSS JOIN` [source](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) that results in a table with a number of rows equal to the Cartesian product of the two tables [source](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cross-join/).

to avoid that you can use `WHERE EXISTS` as:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM schema1.site AS point_table
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 
    FROM schema2.buffer AS poly_table
    where ST_Intersects(point_table.geom, poly_table.geom)
);
```

This allows PostgreSQL to calculate only the spatial join and not have to build a temporary table of the full cross join which takes forever.

Comment: Note that the assumption is to create a new table; PG _should_ handle this elegantly without writing a temporary merge table first; also, there are no hash join nodes in the plan. The `CROSS JOIN` should get translated to an (usually much faster) `INNER JOIN` with the given `WHERE` filter, but if the polygons overlap, the result will have (costly) duplicates. This also invokes the subquery 700M times, run against the less effective polygon index. I do love myself an `EXISTS` whenever possible, but I suspect it is not going to beat a `JOIN` if OP can save the `DISTINCT`.

Comment: If no join qualifier is specified, the default is to compute an INNER join.

Comment: @dr_jts  is my answer above not an improvement over the original method used in the question or are you pointing out that it's not as good as the answer you posted? Also, I'm not seeing anything on google for "postgres join qualifier" is there a specific definition of this term?

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley I was just pointing out that if no JOIN type is specified, then the default is `INNER`.  Postgres reference is here:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM.  And actually I do suspect that using the point table as the driving table is going to be less efficient than the reverse.

Comment: Thanks @Hugh_Kelley. I tried your solution and manage to finish the task in 13 hours. Much better than 24+ hour :)

Comment: @dr_jts, thanks, not intending to be argumentative, trying to understand what's going on with the query. I need to get a better conceptual understanding of the spatial join operations.

Answer (score 6):

It might be faster to use the polygons as the driving table, using the point table index to filter down the large number of records.  This allows PostGIS to optimize the `ST_Intersects` spatial predicate by preparing each polygon.

This can be forced using `LATERAL`:

```
SELECT pt.* FROM schema2.buffer AS poly
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM schema1.site) AS pt 
  ON ST_Intersects(poly.wkb_geometry, pt.geo_loc);
```

If the polygons have a large number of vertices, it can be faster to use `ST_Subdivide` to fragment them before doing the point query:

```
WITH poly AS (
  SELECT ST_Subdivide(wkb_geometry) AS geom FROM schema2.buffer 
)
SELECT pt.* FROM poly
JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM schema1.site) AS pt 
  ON ST_Intersects(poly.geom, pt.geo_loc);
```

Comment: +1 for subdivision, if applicable here. At least with PG>10, the planner _should_ choose the more effective (larger) index no matter the written `JOIN` order. That's also what OPs `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` suggests.

Comment: @dr_jts Thanks for your advice. I also suppose that to use the polygons as the driving table can be a bit faster, but somehow this query took a bit longer than answer from Hugh_Kelley. But anyway, LATERAL is quite a novel join method for me to learn.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  Relative performance might depend on the nature of the data.